# Copying Portfolio IDs to an ordered list

Tags: vba, excel

I have a big excel file with all the transactions from different people on the stock market. The file has multiple sheets representing different months. However to calculate their returns (also other reasons) I need to arrange their Portfolio ID's underneath each other (one Portolio ID number represents a person). As these Portfolio ID's are in every sheet I need to use a macro somehow that copies all these portfolio ID's from all the different sheets (months) underneath each other.

This is what I have until now:

```
Sub apply_autofilter_across_worksheets()
 Dim p As Integer, q As Integer
 p = Worksheets.Count
 For q = 1 To p
 With Worksheets(q)
 .Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="6*"
 End With
 Next q
 End Sub
```

The Portfolio ID's (persons) range from `695678 to 7128631.

The `Criteria1:="6*"` I thought i could use two macros everything starting with number `6*` and everything with a number `7*`.

```
Sub Macro13()
'
' Macro13 Macro
'   

'
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$B$271806").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _   
    "697139"
Sheets("13 feb - 5 Mar ").Select
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$B$259216").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "697139"
Sheets("5 - 15 Mar ").Select
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$B$210584").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "697139"
Sheets("15 Mar - 12 Apr").Select
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$B$240768").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "697139"
Sheets("Blad5").Select
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$B$317496").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "697139"
Sheets("4-13 feb").Select
Range("A181:N184").Select
End Sub
```

This macro works for one Portfolio ID. But then i still have to copy it from each sheet to a new sheet and run it for every Portfolio ID. (I have over thousands of Portfolio ID's)

Please help :)

Comment: To clarify, you basically need these `Portfolio IDs` from all the other sheets copied to a new sheet, while leaving them ***sorted based on which month*** they came from, yes?

Comment: Actually the opposite I want to order them based on Portfolio IDs while NOT leaving them sorted based on which month they came from. However keep in mind that there are so many IDs that it's to big to even fit on one sheet. (1299866 rows)

Comment: So all these `Portfolio ID`s should be copied to a new sheet, sorted from `6*` to `7*`, pretty much this? Are there duplicates?

Comment: Yes exactly and they are duplicates. As these persons bought stocks in the other months (sheets) too. I want to get them arranged by person no matter what month they bought the stocks in.

Comment: Simply put I need a macro to sort that column with portfolio IDs from multiple sheets over multiple sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is tried and tested using the following controls:

1. Created 1 million IDs on my end, generated values between `690k` and `730k`, to match your data closely.
2. I have 5 sheets with 200k IDs each. I created a sheet named `Consolidated` as an output sheet for my results.

The following code runs at approximately 3 seconds on my machine, eliminating all duplicates and generating a completely unique list of 17,186 ID's collected from the 1 million rows of IDs. The list is sorted at the end.

```
Sub GetAllPortfolioIDs()

    Dim WS As Worksheet, ConsWS As Worksheet
    Dim Dict As Object
    Dim RngVal As Variant, ElemVal As Variant
    Dim LRow As Long

    Start = Timer()

    Set ConsWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidated")
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WS.Name <> ConsWS.Name Then
            With WS
                LRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                RngVal = .Range("B2:B" & LRow).Value
            End With
            With Dict
                For Each ElemVal In RngVal
                    If Not .Exists(ElemVal) And Len(ElemVal) > 0 Then
                        .Add ElemVal, Empty
                    End If
                Next ElemVal
            End With
        End If
    Next WS

    With ConsWS
        .Range("A2").Resize(Dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(Dict.Keys)
        .Range("A2").SortSpecial Key1:=.Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess
    End With

    Debug.Print Timer() - Start

End Sub
```

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Hope this works fine for you. I must ask though, as a small favor, what is the run time it's displaying on your end and what version is your Excel? :)